# How to know which patch you have installed a local magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, version

I have a magento installed locally and want to know which patch is installed, so I can install this same patch on another magento site but I don't know how to find out.

The person who installed it, put a file in each file folder and left no documentation.
Is there some kind of plugin or any option to learn what patch is installed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

All applied patches to a Magento installation are stored in the file `app/etc/applied.patches.list`.